# Plot numerical string values in matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot

Suppose I have:

```
x = ['1.34511','0.0234','-0.0890'] 
y = ['0.0987', '0.8763', '-0.0762']
```

How can I plot those values in matplotlib? 
I've already made a search about 'ticks', but I still don't understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit:

My matplotlib 1.2 can plot the string lists fine btw, there is no need for conversion to begin with, just plot them as they are.

You can first convert them to a float32 Numpy array:

```
x = ['1.34511','0.0234','-0.0890'] 
y = ['0.0987', '0.8763', '-0.0762']

x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array(y, dtype=np.float32)

plt.plot(x,y)
```

Or use list comprehension to convert the values to a float:

```
x = ['1.34511','0.0234','-0.0890'] 
y = ['0.0987', '0.8763', '-0.0762']

x = [float(val) for val in x]
y = [float(val) for val in y]

plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: You might use `x=map(float,x)` instead of list comprehension.